# Find youtube iframe and append a div on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to place a div over a youtube iframe embed code but it's doesn't work.
Any ideas?

My code is:

```
$('#iframe').prepend("<div style='width:800px; height:450px; background-color:#fff;'></div");
```

and the classic youtube iframe:

```
<iframe width="800" height="450" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/mllXxyHTzfg?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: This is just not possible..

Comment: Even if i give and id to youtube iframe and append a div on it?

Comment: You cannot affect anything inside an iframe from a different domain.. in effect, a youtube iframe you put on your page is not 'yours'.. all you can do is style the iframe and the elements around it but the iframe content itself is untouchable, If you explain exactly WHAT you are trying to achieve, maybe there's another way about it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a Javascript solution:

```
function coverVideo(){
    // Create an empty div
    var cover = $("<div></div>").appendTo("body");
    cover.css({
        // Position directly over the iframe
        position: "absolute",
        top: $("#iframe").offset().top,
        left: $("#iframe").offset().left,

        // Style as you like
        width: "800px",
        height: "450px",
        background: "#fff"
    });
}
```

Comment: Try adding `id="iframe"` to your iframe, and make sure this code is right before your closing </body> tag (so the iframe exists before you try to run this code), and this should work.

Comment: Missed that the ID hadn't been applied to the iframe, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put your `iframe` inside a container div and add another element next to it:

```
<div id="iframeContainer">
    <iframe width="800" height="450" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/mllXxyHTzfg?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Position the overlay element:

```
#iframeContainer {
    width: 800px;
    height: 450px;
    position: relative;
}

#iframeContainer iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#iframeContainer .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n7et68u8/).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add content to an iframe through javascript.

Add a div outside the iframe and use css positioning to place the div over the iframe.